# Fetching data from JSON.parse array

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, appcelerator

I am stuck in this problem, I am calling a webService that returns me a json response.

now i want to fetch a particular value from that response but after searching on internet and struggling a lot couldn't fix it.

here is my code:

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({

onload : function(e) {
     Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
     alert('success');
     },
 // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
 onerror : function(e) {
     Ti.API.debug(e.error);
     alert('error');
 },
 timeout : 5000
});

var data = {"data":"system.connect"};
xhr.open("POST","http://mytesturl.net/services/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send("method=system.connect");
```

The response is like this:

```
{"#error":false,"#data":{"sessid":"c4likn6vg33hngbpmobisrsbpcjjmf39","user":{"uid":0,"hostname":"102.119.85.120","roles":{"1":"anonymous user"},"session":"","cache":0}},"#response_code":200}
```

from the above response I want to fetch the `sessid` value.
what is the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following can be viewed and tested on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/LPWAJ/).

```
// Given a string of JSON called responseText
var responseText = '{"#error":false,"#data":{"sessid":"c4likn6vg33hngbpmobisrsbpcjjmf39","user":{"uid":0,"hostname":"102.119.85.120","roles":{"1":"anonymous user"},"session":"","cache":0}},"#response_code":200}';

// You can parse it to an object using JSON.parse
var responseObj = JSON.parse(responseText);

// And then access the properties as with any object
console.log(responseObj ["#data"]["sessid"]);
```

Comment: the problem is when i try to save my response like `var myData=this.responseText` and then I log it, it shows null. i dont know why it is showing null but when i log it like `this.responseText` it gives me the exact response