# json parsing not working when accessing objects

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching data from JSON.parse array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129776/fetching-data-from-json-parse-array)

I am new to json stuff dont know even question title is correct

I have following json in obj from this statement 'obj = ko.toJSON(viewModel)';viewmodel is a knockout view.

```
{
"activeColumns": [
    {
        "property": "delete",
        "display": "Delete",
        "checked": true,
        "readonly": true
    },
    {
        "property": "id",
        "display": "ID",
        "checked": false,
        "readonly": true
    },
    {
        "property": "name",
        "display": "Name",
        "checked": false,
        "readonly": false
    },
    {
        "property": "age",
        "display": "Age",
        "checked": false,
        "readonly": false
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
        "selectedFruits": [],
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 44
    },
    {
        "selectedFruits": [],
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ted",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "selectedFruits": [],
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jane",
        "age": 55
    },
    {
        "selectedFruits": [],
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Sue",
        "age": 11
    }
],
"newName": "",
"lastSavedJson": "",
"newAge": "",
"newAttribute": "",
"males": 10,
"females": 90,
"val": 50,
"selectedValue": "select",
"selectedCategory": "select",
"availablecategory": [
    "select",
    "functional",
    "non-functional",
    "technical"
],
"tshirtoptions": [
    "select",
    "S",
    "M",
    "L",
    "XL",
    "XXL"
],
"availableparametertype": [
    "select",
    "range",
    "numeric",
    "percentage",
    "t-shirt"
]
}
```

I am accessing the first array using obj.activeColumns()[0] but it is showing uncaught type error.How to access the different object arrays and their properties and then after how to delete a particular object. thanks...

Comment: Should it be "obj.activeColumns[0]"?

Comment: no showing  'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: now i am able to get the objects.                                      var obj = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
 var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj)
 alert(obj1.rows[0].name)